# How can I determine if a list of discriminated union types are of the same case?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a DU like so:

```
type DU = Number of int | Word of string
```

And suppose I create a list of them:

```
[Number(1); Word("abc"); Number(2)]
```

How can I write a function that would return true for a list of DUs where all the elements are the same case. For the above list it should return false.

Comment: hint : a list with less than 2 items should return `true` otherwise if the first two are the same case and also the tail of the list returns `true` then the final result should also be `true`. *(hint2 : after writing this function, search if you can use a function in `List` module to leverage things a little)*

Comment: Is the question about union types with more than just the 2 cases you show here?

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer unless I'm missing something, how many cases are at play isn't relevant

Comment: Is this the same question as "how do I know every element of a list is the same", or would you expect `[Number(1);Number(2)]` to return true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general approach I'd use here would be to map the union values into tags identifying the cases, and then check if the resulting set of tags has at most one element.

```
let allTheSameCase (tagger: 'a -> int) (coll: #seq<'a>) = 
    let cases = 
        coll
        |> Seq.map tagger
        |> Set.ofSeq
    Set.count cases <= 1
```

For the tagger function, you can assign the tags by hand:

```
 allTheSameCase (function Number _ -> 0 | Word _ -> 1) lst
```

or use reflection (note that you might need to set binding flags as necessary):

```
 open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

 let reflectionTagger (case: obj) = 
    let typ = case.GetType()
    if FSharpType.IsUnion(typ)
        then 
            let info, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(case, typ) 
            info.Tag
        else -1 // or fail, depending what makes sense in the context.
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. This worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In case you wanted to check that the elements of a list are of a specific union case, it's straightforward to provide a predicate function.

```
let isNumbers = List.forall (function Number _ -> true | _ -> false)
```

If you do not care which union case, as long as they are all the same, you need to spell them all out explicitly. Barring reflection magic to get a property not exposed inside F#, you also need to assign some value to each case. To avoid having to think up arbitrary values, we can employ an active pattern which maps to a different DU behind the scenes.

```
let (|IsNumber|IsWord|) = function
| Number _ -> IsNumber
| Word _ -> IsWord

let isSameCase src = 
    src |> Seq.groupBy (|IsNumber|IsWord|) |> Seq.length <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same use case recently and the solution can be done much simpler than complicated reflections or explicit pattern matching, GetType does all the magic:

```
let AreAllElementsOfTheSameType seq = // seq<'a> -> bool
    if Seq.isEmpty seq then true else
    let t = (Seq.head seq).GetType ()
    seq |> Seq.forall (fun e -> (e.GetType ()) = t)
```

Comment: Neat. However, this relies on runtime type checks. F# is a statically typed and checked language. You forgo any support that the F# compiler can give.